# Creating a binary package of a compiled library

Tags: linux, package, libraries, packaging, gentoo

I'm running gentoo and have manually compiled and installed the flann library. I need to create a binary package with the extension of .tar.tbz2 that has all the required files. I tried installing into a separate folder and compressing it but it wasn't recognized as an actual package. (Using make install DESTDIR=folder)

My attempt at the file contained usr as a subdirectory.

Additional info: I'm packaging the library as a part of cross-compiling.

Comment: @user1938107 I had to use emerge to install the packages which automatically generates the binaries. For packages that you can't find an up to date ebuild for, create a local overlay as described here: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Overlay/Local_overlay

Comment: i need a specific boost library, and its not available with the current emerge, aldebaran says not to use emerge --sync.  Have you used the overlay to get over this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add **--prefix=pathtoinstall** to ./configure,then execute make and make install and generate tar from **pathtoinstall**

```
./configure --prefix=pathtoinstall
make
make install
tar -cjvf flann.tar.bz2 pathtoinstall
```

Comment: So it uses CMAKE instead of configure, I ran this:

`cmake CMakeLists.txt -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/nao/libraries/flann/pack
make
make install
tar -cjvf flann.tar.bz2 /home/nao/libraries/flann/pack`

It makes it, but when I try to use it I get 
**[ERROR]:  Binary package exception:
Unknown package type **

Thanks for you answer!

Comment: how you will use flann.tar.bz2 package I mean which command you are using ?

Comment: I'm trying to import it into a qibuild toolchain https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/dev/tools/developing-using-thirdparty.html

This works fine for packages installed from emerge since it auto generates the binary file.

Answer (score 0):

you could write an ebuild for your library and use quickpkg to do the binary package.

Advantage: if a dependency breaks, it's rebuilt (emerge @preserved-rebuild / revdep-rebuild)